# IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint not giving the value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I created the `IBOutlet` of `auto layout constraints` here are the screen shots

[image]

[image]

[image]

and here is the code

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    NSLog(@"View=> x=%f, y=%f, w=%f, h=%f", self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width ,self.view.frame.size.height);

    NSLog(@"V=> x=%f, y=%f, w=%f, h=%f", self.v.frame.origin.x, self.v.frame.origin.y, self.v.frame.size.width ,self.v.frame.size.height);

    NSLog(@"Constant=> w=%f, h=%f", self.vWidth.constant, self.vHeight.constant);
}
```

and here is the output

```
View=> x=0.000000, y=0.000000, w=414.000000, h=736.000000
V=> x=0.000000, y=536.000000, w=414.000000, h=200.000000
Constant=> w=0.000000, h=200.000000
```

Question 1:
When using `auto layouts` is it correct to get frames properties like this `self.v.frame.size.width`, `self.v.frame.size.height` Or I am supposed to use `self.vWidth.constant`, `self.vHeight.constant`?

Question 2:
Why I am getting zero width in this `NSLog(@"Constant=> w=%f, h=%f", self.vWidth.constant, self.vHeight.constant);`?

Comment: Just a tip so save you some typing when printing out rects. You can use  [NSValue valueWithCGRect:self.view.frame] to print x,y,width and height.

Comment: Or even better; NSStringFromCGRect(<#CGRect rect#>)

Comment: Thank your very useful tip :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll get the value(s) in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: but why I am getting the height value?

Comment: Because of the constant, that's a fixed 200. The width is linked to something else and will be calculated once you get into viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: Oh wait! You're talking about the constant in question 2... Well you get 0.0f because the constant IS 0.0f, the constant is something that you set (thus the naming 'constant'). So the 'correct way' is to use CGRectGetWidth(<#CGRect rect#>) after the view did layout it's subviews.

Comment: Thank you :) for great answer.